# image onDraw method don't move in runnable as i give the x-axis pixes to go ahead

Tags: android, canvas

I have a canvas, i have a squre on canvas.

i want to move a image on on this squre x-axis but it is stable how ever i is changed.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //   Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.googlelogo320x480);
            //            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

            myPaint = new Paint();
            myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            canvas1  = canvas;
            canvas1.drawRect(80, 40, 570, 800, myPaint);


            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.horse);
            canvas1.drawBitmap(myBitmap, i, 10, myPaint);

            handler = new Handler();
            runnable = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    canvas1.drawBitmap(myBitmap, i, 10, myPaint);
                            System.out.println(i);

                        if(i<550){
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                        i++;
                    }   
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }   
    }
```

what should i do to move the image on canvas....

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onDraw` is called every time the OS wants to draw the image on screen.  Thus, you do not need to have a runnable loop like that because you may have multiple loops running and drawing the screen.

You can try this.  Remove the handler and loop.  Instead, make `i` private in the class and increase it by 1 every time `onDraw` is called.  Then reset `i` when you've reached its max. Call `invalidate()` at the end of the method.  This will tell the OS to redraw the image again when it is ready.